# How can i use guava cache with a byte[] key?

Tags: java, caching, guava

I created a guava cache:

```
Cache<byte[], byte[]>  = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(1_000_000)
            .expireAfterAccess(20, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build();use
```

but it doesn't find the keys when I call get(). The implementation seems to use equals() to find the key, when I need it to use Arrays.equals().

Is there anyway to set up Cache so that it works this way? Internally, it seems to have the flexibility, as the comparison uses Equivalence rather than a straight equals(), but the CacheBuilder api doesn't seem to have a way to set an Equivalence object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm a bit curious to know why you have byte array as key for an other byte array ...

Comment: Short answer: no, you'll have to wrap the `byte[]` in another object with a proper implementation of `equals` and `hashCode`.  (If I recall correctly, `ByteBuffer` will work here and is built into Java.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Would there be any benefit to adding a `KeyEquality` style evaluation strategy for the cache?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I believe that was considered and rejected.  Trace through https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1571 for details.

Comment: @LouisWasserman _way more users think they need than actually need it_ Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If natural equality is your unique solution (like in a `HashMap`), just wrap your instance in an object that do the job ! JVM works very well with very short living object so don't be annoyed by creating few little objects just for cache querying.

As @LouisWasserman mentioned, you can use [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/ByteBuffer.html). How ever you shoud take care to not modify array backed by cached keys.

Comment: `BigInteger` conflates any arrays with different numbers of leading zeroes.  `ByteBuffer` would do the job, though.

Comment: Can't you suggest an edit on my answer to be authored ? You deserve it ;)

Comment: Of course I can wrap the byte[] in an object, but the cache is fronting a disk-based key-value store so there will be millions of extra objects, rather than a few.  Seems like that's the only option though.  (Sad that arrays are such an afterthought in so many libraries)

Comment: I wouldn't worry about millions of objects until you actually run into performance issues.